Is $P(y(t)\in A)=0$ for every Borel set $A$ with measure zero, for a Ito process $y(t)$ with non-degenerate diffusion?
On some filtered probability space, consider a Ito process in $R^n$ of the form
$$y(t) =\int_0^t b_s ds + \int_0^t\sigma_s dW(s), \quad \forall t \geq 0,$$
with continuous paths. Here $W$ is a Brownian motion.
I would expect that, if $\sigma$ is non degenerate, i.e. $$\left \langle \sigma_s y , y\right \rangle  \geq \lambda |y|^2, \quad \forall y \in  R^n,$$
then  it holds
$$P(y(t)\in A)=0, \quad \forall t \geq 0, $$
for every Borel set  $A \in B(R^n)$ with measure zero. Is this a standard result in the literature?

The ellipticity condition is reminiscent of a condition for PDE problems which involve SDEs in particular. Where have you seen this condition for Ito processes in general?

Well of course, with that condition is similar to the condition for which the infinitesimal generator of an SDE is uniformly elliptic. In my case, have to apply a Ito formula for functions which are twice differentiable in the distributional sense, which Krylov proved under such condition at p.121 [Krylov, Controlled diffusion processes.  Science $&$ Business Media, Vol. 14 (Springer, 2008).] However, given the setting above, I expect that that probability is zero because the process is continuous and the noise. Is this standard and are there results of this kind in the literature?

It could be that this question and answer might be relevant to you.

As mentioned in the comments one nice reference is given in Is the distribution of an Ito diffusion at time t absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure?.

Theorem: Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a solution of the SDE $$dX_t = b(X_t) \, dt + \sigma(X_t) \, dB_t$$ where $\sigma$ is Lipschitz continuous and $b$ of linear growth (i.e. $|b(x)| \leq C (1+|x|)$). Then $X_t$ has a density (with respect to Lebesgue measure) on the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}; \sigma(x) \neq 0\}$ for each $t>0$.


For a proof see Nicolas Fournier & Jacques Printems: Absolute continuity for some one-dimensional processes. (The relevant part of this paper is highly readable; you need some basics on Fourier transform as well as SDEs.)

There they study $\sigma(X_t)$. However, for $\sigma(s)$ it is the same, here is a general density result that covers many cases "Absolute continuity for some one-dimensional processes".

For multivariate see the proof in Theorem 2.3.1 in Nualart's "
The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics": here he uses the Ellipticity condition you mentione
$$\nu^T \sigma(s,X_s)\nu \geq \lambda(s)|\nu|^2.$$

Thanks, but this covers only the one dimensional case. Is there something on the multidimensional case?

@carlos85 ok let me search a bit.

@carlos85 yes, see updated.
